# (Django) Showing simple stats about model instances

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

What would be the correct approach to create a "stats block" which could be used easily?

I've now created a simple page template and view function which returns a list of stats e.g. users and user count by calling User.objects.all().count()

How should this be implemented to be able to include these stats in any template? And perhaps with different styles such as list, inline, bootstrap panel etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it in any template, you probably want to write your own custom **template tag**. This is the relevant Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

Your tag will probably return minimalist data: just the result of `queryset.count()`. The template that you are rendering will place this number in the relevant html context.